# When do we need to clear the scanf buffer?

Tags: c, scanf

I always thought that the "'\n' in buffer" issue only occurs when we are reading characters, 
however, I stumbled upon this issue with the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int height = 0, width = 0;

    while(height < 1 || height > 10|| width < 1 || width > 15){
        printf("Please insert the height(1~10) and width(1~15) of the parallelogram (integers): ");
        if(scanf("%d %d", &height, &width) != 2){
            height = width = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As above, I'm only reading integers with scanf, 
but this piece of code still gets stuck in an infinite loop when I input something invalid.
It's fixed if I clear up the buffer.

So my question is, is this "'\n' in buffer" issue a general thing?
Or does it only happen for special usages? 
If it only happens for special usages, is there some general guideline I need to follow?

Comment: you need to clear the buffer if `scanf` does not return `2`. Then there is something in the buffer which cannot be interpreted as an `int`, for example a letter. Spaces (and new lines at the begin) will be ignored.

Comment: Note that this is **not** the problem of the newline character, but the problem of the invalid characters staying in the `stdin` and `scanf`, seeing them, failing , repeat... FYI, `%d` skips leading whitespace characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general guideline is to **not use `*scanf()` for user input**. Your capabilities to recover gracefully from ill-formatted input are just too limited, the chance of errors too high (as can be seen by the sheer amounts of `*scanf()`-related questions here on SO). The `*scanf()` function family is best used for reading well-formatted input only (i.e. data that was previously written by your own application).

User input is line-based anyway, at least if you're relying on standard input functions.

So **use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a full line of input, then parse it in-memory**. Functions like [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) or [`strtod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) can give very specific feedback at which point exactly they stopped parsing, you can skip back and try a different parse, you have all the [string-handling functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) of the standard at your disposal to pick apart your user's input. And if things go pear-shaped, you can repeat the whole line of input in your error message, adding whatever information on your parsing attempts you like.