# Finding max element in array - program won't recognize last element

Tags: arrays, c, loops, max, scanf

I wrote this little code just to start learning some `if` statements and C coding in general. However, there is an issue. When running it, if the largest element is the last one, the code won't recognize it. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
int num[100];
int max;
int i;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers: \n");
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        scanf("%d\n", &num[i]);
    }
max = num[0];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        if(max < num[i]){
            max = num[i];
        }

    }


printf("The biggest nr is: %d", max);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: First loop starts from 1, instead from 0

Comment: You are taking only  9 numbers in the input. arr[0] contains garbage value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d\n", &num[i]);
}

max = num[0];
```

`max` has an indeterminate value because the loop's counter variable `i` starts at `0`, not `1` which gives the result that the first element of the array wasn't assigned inside of the loop. So you end up assigning this indeterminate value to `max`.

To use an indeterminate value in the following code:

```
if (max < num[i]) {
     max = num[i];
}
```

invokes [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984).

---

> "*However, if I change `i=0`, the program asks me for 11 inputs before moving on. And among those 11 inputs, the program still won't count the last one, if it is the largest.*"
>
> "*When running it, if the largest element is the last one, the code won't recognize it. Why is that?*"

It doesn't actually ask you for an 11th input for any *presumed* 11th array element as you think it does and the last in the loops<sup>1</sup> treated element of the array is not the one you think it is. That is just an impression to you.

This behavior is caused by the newline character in the format string of the `scanf()` call:

```
scanf("%d\n", &num[i]);
```

The newline character (`\n` ) is equal to any white space and with this directive, `scanf()` reads an unlimited amount of white space characters **until** it finds any-non white space character in the input to stop consuming and the control flow continues to the next statement.

[Why does scanf ask twice for input when there's a newline at the end of the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/)

It doesn't ask for the input of the 11th element of the array (as you think it does). It simply needs any non-white space character that the directive fails.

The last element of the array (which is treated inside of the loops<sup>1</sup>) is still the 10th (`num[9]`), not the 11th (`num[10]`) and so is the output correct when you initialize the counter to `0` and it prints:

```
The biggest nr is: 10
```

because `10` is the value of the last treated element `num[9]`.

---

<sup>1) Note that you made a typo at the declaration of `num` -> `int num[100];`. With this you define an array of one hundred elements, but you actually only need one of `10` elements -> `int num[10];`.</sup>

---

Side Note:

- Also always check the return value of `scanf()`!

  ```
  if (scanf("%d\n", &num[i]) != 1)
  {
     // Error routine.
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! When I deleted the newline character and set i=0 the program behaves correctly!

Comment: @SiimHendrik Do you understand a little bit what's going on? It is a little complicated, but you should be able to follow what I meant.

Comment: @ RobertS Yes, I understood what the newline did to my code and where the problem was. Again, thank you!

Comment: @SiimHendrik Newline doesn't belong into a format string in `scanf()`. It is only for `printf()` calls.

Comment: @SiimHendrik And another thing: Give your projects better names. Just the month and the year is not very helpful if you want to find the project back after a couple of months/years/decades. I know is just an example, but better to start soon to be organized well.

Comment: @SiimHendrik I could talk to you in german, but the site forces us to use english which is of course correct, but "Pass immer auf *wie* Du codest!" (Take always care of *how* you coding!) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop should start from 0, not 1.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    scanf("%d\n", &num[i]);
}
```

`max` already starts with an uninitialized value, here be dragons.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. However, if i change i=0, the program asks me for 11 inputs before moving on. And among those 11 inputs, the program still won't count the last one, if it is the largest.

Comment: That is an impossibility. Perhaps the code you posted vs what you are actually running has even more differences. Check whether your condition says `i < 10` or `i <= 10`. It should use `<` operator.

Comment: Your second problem is the scanf function, which often keeps garbage in the buffer. Therefore on the first run of the read-in loop you read a garbage value. Simply print the index of your current loop and the value of the cell in the array to debug this behaviour.

Comment: There are lots of SO questions discussing the many issues of scanf and how to solve them by input checking, buffer flushing and what not. Often the recommandation is to use a different function, which is better usable for recovery after wrong input. Maybe you can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393392/when-do-we-need-to-clear-the-scanf-buffer

Comment: Mhh, interesting. Here I have the IDE and terminal showing the code and the results. Maybe this will shed some light on the problem.
https://imgur.com/a/ScXphJG

As for using a different function, I will try it, however I still would like to know what causes this issue. Is it just, that scanf is a bad function?

Comment: Like I said, you should try to print your index "i" with each iteration to get a better grasp of the issue.
Personally I do not consider functions good or bad, they just have different purposes and handling. You probably can achieve your goal with scanf as well for example by clearing out the buffer and sanity checking your input. On the other hand you could maybe achieve the same in a more convenient way with functions like fgets(). At the end you need to decide, what fits best. Often it makes sense to stick with best practice approaches, which is not scanf in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code one after another:

1. The loop should begin from `0` instead of `1`:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   ```
2. The main problem is here:

   ```
   scanf("%d\n", &num[i]);
   _________^^____________
   ```

   Remove the `\n` and your problem will be fixed.